# Two monitors display

Tags: windows-7, display

I have two monitors for my desktop.

I want to see one Internet Explorer window on one monitor and another window on the other monitor. Is there such a feature in Windows 7?

Answer (score 8):

Go to Control Panel | Display | Screen Resolution, select "Extend these displays" in Multiple displays combo box.

Answer (score 2):

Press Win-P (windows key and P) on the keyboard; this gives quick access to display options (mirror, single, extend), and choose extend.

Then open two IE windows, and drag one of them to the secondary monitor